# Auto picturing feature within specific frame in Android application

Tags: opencv, capture, android

How to make automatically capturing, photo picturing android app when the object fit into the frame i made? (same with the document scanning apps)

Is there any examples or guide (step-by-step)?

Please let me know.

Version: opencv 4.2.0, android studio 3.5.3

The example image:

[standby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mafeS.png)
[after scanning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOLrE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to make automatically capturing, photo picturing android app when the object fit into the frame i made? (same with the document scanning apps)

Is there any examples or guide (step-by-step)?

Please let me know.

Version: opencv 4.2.0, android studio 3.5.3

The example image:

standby after scanning

solved
I fix it my self